# String Pattern Matching in C

Tags: c, string

I was trying this pattern matching method in C but whenever I give all the input, the vscode terminal waits for a while and just stops the program without any warnings/message. Can anyone point to what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char STR[100], PAT[100], REP[100], ANS[100];
    int i, m, j, k, flag, slP, slR, len;
    i = m = k = j = flag = len = 0;
    printf("\nMain String: ");
    gets(STR);
    printf("\nPattern String: ");
    gets(PAT);
    slP = strlen(PAT);
    printf("\nReplace String: ");
    gets(REP);
    slR = strlen(REP);
    while (STR[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (STR[i] = PAT[j])
        {
            len = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < slP; k++)
            {
                if (STR[k] = PAT[k])
                    len++;
            }
            if (len == slP)
            {
                flag = 1;
                for (k = 0; k < slR; k++, m++)
                    ANS[m] = REP[k];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ANS[m] = STR[i];
            m++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("\nPattern not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        ANS[m] = '\0';
        printf("\nResultant String: %s\n", ANS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilers made after 1989 typically have a warning against the old and tiresome assignment in condition bug `if (STR[i] = PAT[j])`. How did you manage to get this code compiling cleanly and on which compiler? For those insisting on using assignment in conditions (very questionable practice), the code would look something like `if ((STR[i] = PAT[j]) != '\0')`

Comment: Compilers made after 2011 refuse the `gets` function. It would seem that you have a very old compiler and even older learning material.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- using `gets()` is risky, this function was removed from the C Standard because it cannot be used safely.
- `if (STR[i] = PAT[j])` copied the pattern to the string. You should use:

  ```
    if (STR[i] == PAT[j])
  ```
- similarly, `if (STR[k] = PAT[k])` is incorrect. You should compare `PAT[k]` and `STR[i + k]`:

  ```
    if (STR[i + k] == PAT[k])
  ```
- you should test for buffer overflow for the output string as replacing a short string by a larger one may produce a string that will not fit in `ANS`
- you do not increment `i` properly.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getstr(const char *prompt, char *dest, int size) {
    int c, len = 0;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (len + 1 < size)
            dest[len++] = c;
    }
    if (size > 0)
        dest[len] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    if (c == EOF && len == 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return len;
}

int main() {
    char STR[100], PAT[100], REP[100], ANS[100];
    int i, m, k, flag;

    if (getstr("Main String: ", STR, sizeof STR) < 0)
        return 1;
    if (getstr("Pattern String: ", PAT, sizeof PAT) < 0)
        return 1;
    if (getstr("Replace String: ", REP, sizeof REP) < 0)
        return 1;

    i = m = flag = 0;
    while (STR[i] != '\0') {
        if (STR[i] == PAT[0]) {    // initial match
            // compare the rest of the pattern
            for (k = 1; PAT[k] != '\0' && PAT[k] == STR[i + k]; k++)
                continue;
            if (PAT[k] == '\0') {  // complete match
                flag = 1;
                // copy the replacement string
                for (k = 0; REP[k] != '\0'; k++) {
                    if (m + 1 < sizeof ANS)
                        ANS[m++] = REP[k];
                }
                i += k;   // skip the matching characters
                continue;
            }
        }
        // otherwise copy a single character
        if (m + 1 < sizeof ANS)
            ANS[m++] = STR[i];
        i++;
    }
    ANS[m] = '\0';
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("Pattern not found!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Resultant String: %s\n", ANS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also `STR[K] == PAT[K]` makes no sense, i think `k` should be the offset additionally to `i`, not a comparison starting at 0 again